# Cannot get xmlhttprequest send method to work

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Forgive the simplistic question.  I'd like to pass a variable from javascript to php and I understand this can be done with an xmlhttprequest object.  So I built a test script to figure out how to do this.

I'm using XAMPP and I placed the following files, main.php and test.php into their proper location in the htdocs folder.

main.php tries to pass a variable to test.php using an xmlhttprequest.  test.php simply echos the variable.  I then try and display the echoed result in main.php.

When I load main.php in a browser and view source, I expect to see the variable echoed.  Instead I see an error message that the variable that was supposed to be passed to test.php is undefined.

Any help would be most welcome.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Main</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?var1=hello", true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);

        <?php include("test.php"); ?>

    });

    </script>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Here is the code in test.php which resides in the same folder as main.php

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['var1'];
echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're running the request in asynchronous mode, so check for ready state change:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 

xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?var1=hello", true); 
xmlhttp.send(null); 

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
   alert(xmlhttp.responseText)
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately it did not seem to work.  When I loaded main.php and viewed source  I see the following error.  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: var1 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\testPAGE\php\test.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />

Comment: I double checked that my apache server is running.

Comment: I don't really know php, but I know you can't load your test.php script before you call the GET method in an AJAX request.  Why are you including it if you're using ajax to call it?

Comment: @syd, I updated my answer to include an alert() of whatever was returned by the ajax request.

Comment: Ah yes, I see the alert box with the word 'hello' in it. So I guess the variable is being passed from main.php to test.php.  Now that I know the variable is being passed correctly I think I can take it from here. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that it looks like you're using jQuery (if it is Sizzle, ignore the rest of this),
so you don't need to use that! jQuery has built in Ajax methods that simplify it greatly!

```
$.ajax({
    url:"test.php",
    method:"get",
    data:{
             var1:"hello"
         }
}).done(function(data){
     alert(data);
});
```

Will create an XMLHttpRequest and send it.